# Referencing parameter lookup_array in function match in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I want to use the match function in Excel the following way: match(True, D2:J2>=K1,0), to find the smallest value that is greater than or equal to lookup_value. My problem is how to change the row number in the array, since the row number is on his part the result of a match function.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your baseline formula is:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,D2:K2>=K1,0)
```

which looks at row #2:

[image]

To change that row, lets put **7** in cell **A1** to mean use row #7.  We change the formula to:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(D:D,A1):INDEX(K:K,A1)>=K1,0)
```

[image]

So the value in **A1** defines the row that `MATCH()` should use.

**EDIT#1:**

Here is another example of using `INDEX()` to return a **cell reference.**

Say we have data in column **A**.  We want the user to be able to select parts of the column *(start and stop rows)* and sum the part.  However, we don't want the user to tinker with the formula.  In fact we are going to lock the formula cell so the user can't destroy the formula.  We tell the user to put the start row in **D1** and the end row in **D2**.

We put the formula in cell **D3**:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,D1):INDEX(A:A,D2))
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfect, although I don't understand how the result of a Index function could be  a cell reference instead of a cell value.

Comment: @Taki  An excellent comment! `INDEX()` can be used in two different ways.  The usual way is to return the **value** of a cell in some location in a block.  The second way is to use `INDEX()` to return a **cell reference.**  My answer uses this second way.

Comment: @Taki  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Well, now that you mention it, I did read the documentation to INDEX more carefully. It turns out that I missed that part of the explanation where described the use of the function in the reference form. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Taki  `INDEX()` is pretty powerful